# Avoiding a piece of boilerplate code resetting page boundaries (of p:dataTable) being repeated in managed beans

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, lazydatamodel

While deleting rows from an iterating component like a `<p:dataTable>`, the current page needs to be reset to its immediate previous page, if all of the rows in **the last page** have been deleted. This is unfortunately not automated in `<p:dataTable>` with `LazyDataModel<T>`.

Linguistically, if a data table contains 11 pages with 10 rows per page and all of the rows on the 11th page i.e the last one are deleted, it should get the 10th page automatically (i.e. the immediate previous page) but this does not happen automatically (the current page remains stationary (11th) as if the data table itself gets emptied) unless explicitly coded somewhere in the associated backing bean.

Informally, the corresponding pseudo code segment would look something like the following.

```
if (rowCount <= (ceiling)((first + 1) / pageSize) * pageSize - pageSize) {
    first -= pageSize;
}
```

Where `first` is the page offset (starting with `0`), `pageSize` indicates rows per page and `rowCount` indicates the total number of rows from the associated data-store/database.

Practically :

```
@Override
public List<Entity> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, Object> filters) {

    // ...

    int rowCount = service.getRowCount();
    setRowCount(rowCount);

    // ...

    if (pageSize <= 0) {
        // Add an appropriate FacesMessage.
        return new ArrayList<Entity>();
    } else if (first >= pageSize && rowCount <= Utility.currentPage(first, pageSize) * pageSize - pageSize) {
        first -= pageSize;
    } else if (...) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    return service.getList(first, pageSize, map, filters);
    // SortMeta in List<SortMeta> is PrimeFaces specific.
    // Thus, in order to avoid the PrimeFaces dependency on the service layer,
    // List<SortMeta> has been turned into a LinkedHashMap<String, String>()
    // - the second last parameter (named "map") of the above method call.
}
```

The static utility method `Utility#currentPage()` is defined as follows.

```
public static int currentPage(int first, int pageSize) {
    return first <= 0 || pageSize <= 0 ? 1 : new BigDecimal(first + 1).divide(new BigDecimal(pageSize), 0, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING).intValue();
}
```

This is a piece of boilerplate code and should be avoided being repeated all over the place - in every managed bean using a `<p:dataTable>` with `LazyDataModel<T>`.

Is there a way to automate this process?

Comment: Best way is asking PF guys to fix paginator logic for that.

Comment: And for the time being put it in a baseclass?

Comment: The piece of code had already been repeated in every managed bean using a `<p:dataTable>` with `LazyDataModel<T>` in the whole project. Therefore, moving it to a super class requires drastic changes in the current design - difficult to adopt.

Comment: PF, DataTable is the best open source choice, but many features like pagination must be completly rewrited, in my case i rewrite the hole Server and Client side for professional performence

Comment: @NassimMoualek: please substantiate. E.g. create a blogpost where you elaborate on all the details. PF datatable works nice for us with good professional performance

Comment: @Tiny: then I think your are at a loss. Other then maybe overriding the PF classes. And no one can write a valid answer for **you**

Comment: It is taken up to the issue tracker on [GitHub](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/668).

Comment: @Tiny, was the issue deleted for some reason? 404.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov : The issue is there with no comments and no other participants yet. You will need to login there to view the page.

Comment: Logged in, still 404. Weird.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov : Issues are likely to be reported somewhere else then which I don't know. I don't know how to make them publicly available.